# I got errors: "QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component" and "qrc:/main.qml:-1 File not found"

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlapplicationengine

I created a Qt Widgets application, then added a qml named "*main.qml*" to it. My files are *dialog.cpp*, *dialog.h*, *dialog.ui*, *main.cpp*, *untitiled9.pro*, *main.qml* in *qml.qrc*

*main.cpp*:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include<QtQml>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog w;
    // w.show();
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    // engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc://main.qml")));
    engine.load(QUrl::fromLocalFile("qrc:///main.qml"));
    return a.exec();
}
```

I wrote `QT += qml quick widgets` in *untitled9.pro*.
I didn't modified other codes, how did this happen?
This is my first question in stackoverflow, I try to make my question clear.

Comment: `QUrl(":/main.qml")`

Answer (score 2):

QUrl::fromLocalFile will build a local file based url. So, just remove "qrc:///" in the code. Copy main.qml into build target directory if necessary.

Sample code:

```
engine.load(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));
```